# How to print a div without PDF saving option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print a div without 'Save as PDF' option as a destination. I tried like this but could not. It is showing 'Save as PDF' with print option.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintDiv() {
        var contents = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
        var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
        frame1.name = "frame1";
        frame1.style.position = "absolute";
        frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
        document.body.appendChild(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            document.body.removeChild(frame1);
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Define a default printer on your system ..?

Comment: Printers are not part of the javascript "eco-system", they're part of the users system or browser (in the case of "Save as PDF") which can also be [controlled by enterprise policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/39245642/i-need-to-disable-the-save-as-pdf-option-from-print-in-chrome-browser?hl=en) (apparently)

Comment: Even if you could disable "Save as PDF", the user may have other PDF print drivers installed, eg "Microsoft Print to PDF" or "CutePDF Writer"

Comment: Then you need to remove all the other printers from the system, but the one you want to use to print. As freedomn-m stated, those options are defined at system level, you can't modify the options with JS.

Comment: Maybe a question for the https://superuser.com/ stack?

Comment: As @freedomn-m says, the control you're after can't realistically be done from a web app. Plus, even if it could, the user could just screenshot or scan it and save it as a PDF anyway